# Sorting Keys or Key objects with Java

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out how to order a `List<Key>` where I need to put the root key into the top of the List, the challenge is the method the outputs the List does not output in any order.

The root key is the one with `parentKey = null` and child keys are those with `parentKey`s

What is the right approach to deal with this kind of problem?

[image]

See parentKey:

[image]

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: Did you try Googling stuff like "sorting a list in Java"?

Comment: I understand the element with `parentKey==null` should be on top. Does it matter how the other elements are ordered?

Comment: use a SortedList, you will have to define how the program sort your values (here you will have to tell him to sort it using keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach would be to write a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) so that [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) works as you intend it. Since you don't say how the other keys should be sorted, the only thing I can say about this comparator is that it should consider the key that has no parent as the lowest one.